# Как получить JSON из глобальной переменной JS на Java?

Tags: java, веб-программирование

Мне требуется экспортировать данные с сайта, к исходном коду сайта или к базе данных доступа нет. Нужные данные в формате JSON хранятся в глобальной переменной, к которой можно обратиться при помощи консоли браузера с помощью команды `window.__timetableData`. Можно ли каким то образом вызывать эту команду по URL сайта при помощи Java? Слышал, что с таким может помочь Selenium Web Driver, но он довольно обширный, поэтому не знаю, что именно мне нужно.

Comment: Эти данные JSON лежат на вашем сайте или нужно распарсить страницу и вытащить данные? Selenium помогает с тем, что может вытащить данные, которые лежат на страничке. А для обмена информацией нужно использовать HTTP запросы к серверу.

Comment: @SergeyK. к серверу доступа нет, нужно каким то образом эти данные достать с странички.

Comment: Так как это информация, которая сохраняется в памяти интерпретатора во время исполнения с помощью парсера её не достать. Могу предложить лишь два варианта:
1. Посмотреть откуда оно приходить, вероятно с какого-нибудь HTTP запроса и выполнять этот запрос.
2. Написать JS скрипт, чтобы во время работы сайта отправлять HTTP запрос к своему JAVA приложению.

Comment: @SergeyK. А с помощью чего на JS можно обращаться за доступом к глобальным переменным другого сайта, чтобы в дальнейшем направить их в Java приложение?

Answer (score 0):

Всё оказалось проще, чем я думал. Глобальная переменная `windows.__timetableData` лежала в `html` документе странницы. При помощи библиотеки `Jsoup` я спарсил все теги `<script>` и нашёл нужный. Далее с помощью регулярных выражений вытащил нужный `Json`.

```
Elements scripts = document.getElementsByTag("script");
Element script = scripts.get(4);

if(script.data().contains("window._timetableData")) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\[[^;]*)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(script.data());

    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
    } else {
        System.err.println("No match found!");
    }
}
```

С решением очень помог ответ: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47766187/how-to-fetch-variables-inside-script-entry-using-jsoup

Comment: Может эти данные константные, раз лежат в скрипте и нет смысла их парсить, а можно сразу сохранить у себя?

Comment: @SergeyK. Для конкретного URL - да, но если изменить переменную пути, то на другой страннице будет уже другой Json, я хотел этот процесс как-то автоматизировать, чтобы можно было всегда получить нужный Json на странницах с разной информацией.